# Show a popup with custom numeric keypad beside a view

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

Probably this was answered before but I haven't found a good answer yet. I'd like to show a numeric keypad when an user press a `textView`. I already have done that part. What I'm missing is to show a popup with the numeric keypad beside my textview.

Comment: What do you mean beside your textView? Are you referring to when the phone is landscape? Or keeping a permanent numeric keypad open? Or altering its position?

Comment: It's like showing a popup with a numeric pad beside a `textview`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

In summary this is what I did:

1. Given my board `TableLayout` I added a `RelativeLayout` as a parent, so that I can overlay views.
2. Added my keypad as another `TableLayout` just below my board `TableLayout` (so, I have two `TableLayout`s: one on top for my *board* and the one below for my *keypad*. The keypad is hidden as default, I'll manage the visibility in my program.
3. Within my `clickListener` I show the keypad depending of the returned values of my board's box view, `getX()` and `getY()` .

The result is pretty nice:
[image]